# Error in $Ajax ASP.NET web method call [async]

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asynchronous

I am working over async web method (asmx file) and I need to call this method throughout an ajax jquery method however I am facing a lot of issues because the method uses also Entity Framework to run some other things.

Here is JavaScript:

```
function SubmitStripeForm() {
        // event.preventDefault();
        stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Inform the user if there was an error.
                var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                // Send the token to your server.
                // stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                console.log();
                var myToken = result.token.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:54355/Account/API/Stripe.asmx/MyStripePayment",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    async: false,
                    data: '{Tok: "' + myToken + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.d) {
                            console.log("Good");
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Bad");
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        console.log("HORRIBLE");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is the web method in asp.net c#:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public async void MyStripePayment(string Tok)
    {   
        string MyToken = Tok;
        using (var context = new CompanyEntities())
        {
            var collection = (from p in context.COMPANY where p.Id == Company_Id select p);
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                // Validation of the object
                BillingManagement.Michael Maik = new BillingManagement.Michael();
                Maik.name = "Michael";
                Maik.id = "114060502";
                Maik.number = "83290910";


                #region Send Information To Stripe
                CancellationToken Token = new CancellationToken();
                string Url = "http://localhost:5000/testing/give-your-data";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Url))
                {
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Maik);
                    using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                    {
                        request.Content = stringContent;

                        using (var response = await client
                            .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, Token)
                            .ConfigureAwait(false))
                        {
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            string resString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(resString);
                            string message = (string)jObject["message"];
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion

            }
        }
```

and this is the error displayed:

```
POST http://localhost:54355/Account/API/Stripe.asmx/MyStripePayment 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `Try/Catch` to get more information about the error? obviously it is something internal, better used it like that and try again to see what error it is.

```
try
{
    // Code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   console.writeLine(ex);         
}
```

OR

You put an intervention in the catch to be able to see in local variables the values ​​of the "Ex" or save the error somewhere to read it later.